# Find a common pattern among a set of URLs

Tags: amazon-web-services, url, mapreduce, distributed-computing

I have a file of URLs. The file looks like this

> ```
> http://www.example.com/images/1
> http://www.example.com/images/2
> .
> .
> .
> http://www.example.com/images/2000
> http://www.example.org/p/q/r/1/s/t
> http://www.example.org/p/q/r/2/s/t
> http://www.example.org/p/q/r/3/s/t
> .
> .
> .
> http://www.example.org/p/q/r/5000/s/t
> ```

and so on. The URLs are not sorted. I have just put it out in sorted manner to explain it clearly.

I have to process these URLs such that if there is one word(word between 2 slashes) different between 2 URLs and number of such occurrences is > 1000, I replace that word by *

For example, in the above file, I will have

> ```
> http://www.example.com/images/*
> http://www.example.org/p/q/r/*/s/t
> ```

The file size is in hundreds of GBs. Can someone help me out with this?

Comment: Are these files stored in S3?

Comment: Yes. I can even use solutions using Map Reduce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have proposed a MapReduce algorithm for this problem in [this paper](http://users.ics.forth.gr/~kstef/docs/bigdata15a.pdf) (end of page 3), which is a parallel adaptation of the sequential "infix extraction" algorithm, introduced in [another paper](http://delivery.acm.org/10.1145/1970000/1967557/p453-papadakis.pdf?ip=139.91.183.56&id=1967557&acc=ACTIVE%20SERVICE&key=5641A0C343C36AC1%2ED75FDAEEC7916800%2E4D4702B0C3E38B35%2E4D4702B0C3E38B35&CFID=889527370&CFTOKEN=92958316&__acm__=1484579795_59dfbc089421f3f1baefaf25229b47d6) (page 4, Algorithm 1).

Here, I quote the sequential algorithm:

```
1. sort URIs
2. tokenize URIs at all special characters
3. cluster URIs according to the first n tokens 
4. for all clusters do
5.   for all URIs in the cluster do
6.     for all possible prefixes do
7.       find the set of (distinct) next tokens T
8.     end for
9.   end for
10.   for all URIs in the cluster do
11.     set as a prefix the one with the largest |T|
12.     set as infix the substring following the prefix
13.   end for
14. end for
```

The main idea of the parallel version is that you create the clusters (step 3), by using as map output key the second token of the URI (after http://), and then perform similar operations to steps 4-14) in each reducer, i.e., in each cluster. 
The source code of our parallel version can be found [here](https://github.com/vefthym/ParallelBlocking/tree/master/PrefixInfix/src/infixExtractionNewIds).

After you extract the "infix" of each URI, you can easily replace it with any character you wish, e.g., `'*'`. Keep in mind that this is  an expensive process, which makes sense to be done in MapReduce, only when you have millions+ of URIs, which it seems that you do have.